# Specified fields in ModelSerializer not being filtered

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple view with "athletes" should only show a name, and id, with some extra related data. However I am getting back the entire dataset from an record.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def get_by_years(request):
    athletes = AthleteProfile.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    athletes_json = NotesAthleteSerializer(athletes, many=True)

    return Response(athletes_json.data)
```

I am expecting this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": 215,
        "first_name": "Joseph",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "graduation_year": 2016,
        "notes": "fdgdfg wew",
    }
]
```

Instead, it's providing all the details like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 215,
        "first_name": "Joseph",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "graduation_year": 2016,
        "notes": "fdgdfg wew",
        "email": "joedoe@gmail.com",
        "date_of_birth": null,
        "mobile_number": "123-234-23271",
        "team_name": "Wildcats",
        "coach_name": "",
        "coach_email": "",
        "coach_number": "",
        "event_seen": "NA",
        "jersey_number": 1,
        "rank": 2,
        "public_record": false,
        "notify_key": "f9781efee667d26cdeb6cead447e49bdd8a836a3",
        "notified_on": "2016-11-02T10:58:37.131000Z",
        "level_of_interest": "1",
        "user": null,
        "owner": 30,
        "sport_position": null,
        "next_step": null,
        "next_steps": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

Here is my setup for serialization:

```
class NotesAthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AthleteProfile
        field = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
```

Am I initializing the "NotesAthleteSerializer" incorrectly?

I've tried several other ways of defining the serialization such as:

```
class NotesAthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    graduation_year = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    notes = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AthleteProfile
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
```

and

```
class NotesAthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AthleteProfile
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
```

and

```
class NotesAthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    graduation_year = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    notes = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AthleteProfile
        field = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
```

Comment: Use `read_only_fields` to hide fields in required serializers

Comment: I tried that and the same thing happens, I switched NotesAthleteSerializer with read_only_fields from fields.

Comment: In each serializer , field list contains only fields which is according to your needs. No need for  including all fields of model .

Comment: @Deep3015 I've simplified the question with your suggestions, nothing seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a complete idiot, I had "field" and not "fields"....

```
class NotesAthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AthleteProfile
        field = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
```

Instead it needed to be:

```
class NotesAthleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AthleteProfile
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'graduation_year', 'notes')
```